# Option type 'A' not being found

Tags: scala

Below code causes compiler error :

```
Multiple markers at this line
- not found: type A
- not found: type A
```

at line `def headOption` :

```
object LazyList {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")

  sealed trait Stream[+A]
  case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
  case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

  object Stream {

    def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
      lazy val head = hd
      lazy val tail = tl
      Cons(() => head, () => tail)
    }

    def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

    def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
      if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

    def headOption : Option[A] = this match {
      case Empty => None
      case Cons(h, t) => Some(h())
    }

  }


}
```

But I think the function is defined correctly ? Since A is a generic type it should not cause this compiler error ?

Comment: There's no generic type `A` in scope at the point `headOption` is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `def headOption` into the Stream trait. Currently, it's in the Stream companion object. An object doesn't have a type parameter, because an object is just one determinate thing in memory, with a completely specific type. The Stream trait describes many possible Stream objects, each of which can have a different type, corresponding to the type filled in for `A` when the object is created.

Notice that you intend your `this` in `headOption` to refer to a specific Stream, not to the Stream companion object.

Answer (score 1):

`headOption` should be defined as polymorphic function like what you did for `empty` and `apply`. So you need to add type annotation to your function as follow:

```
def headOption[A]: Option[A] = ...
```

However generally `headOption` should be moved to the trait and defining it in companion object is wrong. If you move it to the trait, the trait is typed so you do not need to add type annotation to the function and your current implementation will work.